# How to use "cluster" features in OrientJS?

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I'm fresh to OrientDB world and eager to use OrientDB/OrientJS in production.

After reading the documents related, I am puzzled with using "cluster" features in OrientJS. The features are involved in  "`CREATE CLASS`", "`ALTER CLASS ADDCLUSTER`", "`create records in the specified cluster`", "`select records from clusters`", "`LiveQuery`", etc.

Please kindly shed some light on these questions.

Comment: James Root, tks for correcting the typo "puzzle"!

Comment: You can just use sql.
From orientjs you can use db.query api

Answer (score 1):

I created a DB to try your request about cluster features.

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2424,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});

var db = server.use({
    name: 'OrientJStest',
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});
```

1. **CREATE CLASS (`Place`):**

   ```
   db.class.create('Place', 'V')
       .then(function (Class) {
           console.log("Created class "+Class.name);
   });
   ```

   **Output**:

   ```
   Created class Place
   ```
2. **CREATE PROPERTY (`Name`):**

   ```
   db.class.get('Place')
       .then(function (Class) {
       console.log('Class: ' + Class.name);
       Class.property.create({
           name: 'name',
           type: 'String'
       })
       .then(function (newProp) {
           console.log('Property created: ' + newProp.name);
       });
   });
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Class: Place
   Property created: name
   ```
3. **ALTER CLASS (`Place`) ADDCLUSTER (`place2`):**

   ```
   db.query('ALTER CLASS Place ADDCLUSTER place2')
       .then(function (cluster) {
           console.log(cluster);
   });
   ```
4. **INSERT INTO CLUSTER (`place`):**

   ```
   db.insert().into('cluster:place')
       .set({name:'London'}).all()
       .then(function (record) {
           console.log('Created record: ',record);
   });
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Created record:  [ { '@type': 'd',
       '@class': 'Place',
       name: 'London',
       '@rid': { [String: '#15:0'] cluster: 15, position: 0 },
       '@version': 1 } ]
   ```
5. **INSERT INTO CLUSTER (`place2`):**

   ```
   db.insert().into('cluster:place2')
       .set({name:'Manchester'}).all()
       .then(function (record) {
           console.log('Created record: ',record);
   });
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Created record:  [ { '@type': 'd',
       '@class': 'Place',
       name: 'Manchester',
       '@rid': { [String: '#16:0'] cluster: 16, position: 0 },
       '@version': 1 } ]
   ```
6. **SELECT FROM CLUSTER (`place`):**

   ```
   db.select().from('cluster:place').all()
       .then(function (vertex) {
           console.log('Vertexes found: ',vertex);
   });
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Vertexes found:  [ { '@type': 'd',
       '@class': 'Place',
       name: 'London',
       '@rid': { [String: '#15:0'] cluster: 15, position: 0 },
       '@version': 1 } ]
   ```
7. **SELECT FROM CLUSTER (`place2`):**

   ```
   db.select().from('cluster:place2').all()
       .then(function (vertex) {
           console.log('Vertexes found: ',vertex);
   });
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Vertexes found:  [ { '@type': 'd',
       '@class': 'Place',
       name: 'Manchester',
       '@rid': { [String: '#16:0'] cluster: 16, position: 0 },
       '@version': 1 } ]
   ```
8. **SELECT FROM ALL CLUSTERS OF CLASS `Place`:**

   ```
   db.select().from('Place').all()
       .then(function (vertex) {
           console.log('Vertexes found: ',vertex);
   });
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Vertexes found:  [ { '@type': 'd',
       '@class': 'Place',
       name: 'London',
       '@rid': { [String: '#15:0'] cluster: 15, position: 0 },
       '@version': 1 },
     { '@type': 'd',
       '@class': 'Place',
       name: 'Manchester',
       '@rid': { [String: '#16:0'] cluster: 16, position: 0 },
       '@version': 1 } ]
   ```

As you can see, the vertexes are in the same class but in different clusters.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Sunrise, did you have a chance to try my solution ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed samples. I am sure to try your solution in next days, and will comment here.

Comment: Hi @Sunrise, glad to have been helpful.

Comment: Hi @Sunrise, I forgot one thing: I created only one new cluster `place2` in the class `Place` because, by default, a cluster with the class name in lower case is created (in this case `place`).

Comment: Hi @Sunrise, have you tried the `cluster` features in OrientJS ?

Comment: Hi @LucaS, much sorry for not trying in time. Before that, I have to confirm some other more important features, about which I have posted  questions here or at LinkedIn(Luca).  Once I try "cluster", I will comment here.

Comment: Hi @Sunrise, did you test the cluster features in `OrientJS` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, a cluster "is a very generic way to group records", default the relationship between class and cluster, is 1:1, then for each created class is created by its relative cluster.
you can always specify in what cluster put the new records/documents/vertices/edges. So let's create 1 cluster per letter and add it to the class. Example:

create cluster employee_a // cluster id = 12
alter class Employee addcluster 12

create cluster employee_b // cluster id = 13
alter class Employee addcluster 13

create cluster employee_c // cluster id = 14
alter class Employee addcluster 14

How to manage the clusters depends on your needs.
then according to the strategy you choose the new vertex will be saved accordingly (ex: using "round robin" 1 vertex saved in cluster 12, 1 vertex saved in cluster 13, 1 vertex saved in cluster 14.

To obtain the data that are present in a specific cluster:
select from Cluster:12

Comment: I got what you mean. But what I care is how to coding with 'cluster' in OrientJS.